# Mac : "gnupg 2.3.8 is already installed and up-to-date" BUT "zsh: command not found: gpg"

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, environment, gnupg

Hello I need `gnupg` in order to install RVM. When running from bash `brew install gnupg`, I get the following error :

[image]

However when running `gnupg` I get :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the program is not on PATH

You should find where Ehre program is saved and then add it to PATH or move it to another location (But this might break things)

Comment: thank you. I made "which gnupg" to check the gnupg path and "pwd" to see my current path. They were different.